# Changing class attribute ng-class

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I am trying to set `margin-left` attribute:

**HTML**

```
<section ng-model="isTrue" ng-class="isTrue ? 'true' : 'false'">
```

**CSS**

```
 .wrapper > section {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I am trying to set `margin-left: 220` if false and `margin-left: 0' if true.

Comment: I answered your question but just curious. why you are putting the ng-model on section tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different class for each:

```
<section ng-model="isTrue" ng-class="isTrue ? 'no-margin-class' : 'my-margin-class'">

.no-margin-class {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.my-margin-class {
    margin-left: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<section ng-model="isTrue" ng-class="{ myclass: isTrue }">
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper > section.myclass {
    margin-left: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to use ng-class.

**HTML**

```
<section ng-model="isTrue" ng-class="{'marginLeftZero' : !isTrue }"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper section {
  margin-left:220px;
}

.wrapper section.marginLeftZero {
  margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code should be in below way

```
<section ng-model="isTrue" ng-class="{wrapper: isTrue}">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7SXLRX6tl5hPHJlllc5o?p=preview.

This should resolve your problem